# Change Format of Values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to sql and am wondering if its possible to format how the values look within their respective columns. For example I am creating a table called FLATJSON2 in the following format

```
create or replace table flatjson2 as select 
 value:"AccountID"::varchar as AccountID,
 value:"AvgMarginPerEE"::varchar as AvgMarginPerEE,
 value:"CloseDate"::timestamp as CloseDate,
 value:"CloseReason"::varchar as CloseReason,
 value:"CloseWonLoss"::varchar as CloseWonLoss,
 value:"Name"::varchar as Name,
 value:"NewOrRepeatCustomer"::varchar as NewOrRepeatCustomer,
 value:"OpportunityAmount"::int as OpportunityAmount,
 value:"OpportunitySource"::varchar as OpportunitySource,
 value:"OpportunityStage"::varchar as OpportunityStage,
 value:"ProductCount"::int as ProductCount,
 value:"SetUpFee"::varchar as SetUpFee,
 value:"AGFeeRate"::int as AGFeeRate,
 value:"pyDateValue"::timestamp as CreationDate,
 value:"pyDecimalValue"::int as AnnualSalary,
 value:"pyID"::varchar as CaseID,
 value:"pyOwnerUserID"::varchar as OwnerUserID,
 value:"pzInsKey"::varchar as pzInsKey,
 value:"pxPages":"crmIndexProducts":"EstimatedEmployerBurden"::int as EstimatedEmployerBurden,
 value:"pxPages":"crmIndexProducts":"EstimatedMargin"::int as EstimatedMargin,
 value:"pxPages":"crmIndexProducts":"MonthlySalary"::int as MonthlySalary,
 value:"pxPages":"crmIndexProducts":"OppProductID"::varchar as OppProductID,
 value:"pxPages":"crmIndexProducts":"AGFee"::int as AGFee,
 value:"pxPages":"crmIndexProducts":"CountryID"::int as Country

 from snowtable, lateral flatten (input =>jsontext);
```

I am trying to make the date columns to be in the format 1/30/2019 and the Money columns to be in this format $2,000.

Can I accomplish when I am creating the table?

Comment: The only way to do that in Snowflake would be to store the dates and the "money" columns as VARCHAR instead of date and number data types.  Snowflake stores the data in a native format, but you can always select that data and format it during your select.  For example, you can use the TO_VARCHAR() function to define the date format you wish to see the data in.

Comment: Okay could you show me an example of using TO_VARCHAR() function in the SELECT command to change a format?

Comment: Second this, what @Mike Walton said. Just a thought from what I'm seeing, a popular flow is snowflake -> dbt -> snowflake and keeping a raw and model schema to separate out your incoming raw data, transforming via dbt in your database, then feeding that back into snowflake -- it helps to keep things relatively organized.

For the sake of readability, it would read as a model that is making those transformations directly from your raw source.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter Snowflake date formats using [parameters](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html), and that will presumably show in the Snowflake Web GUI, but will not be exported in any way.

To hardcode conversion into VARCHAR you can use eg:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('2019-01-30'::DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') DT, TO_CHAR(2000, '$MI999,999,999');
```

Snowflake only has 2 digit days and months.